# jQuery ajax errors out if file not exists, even though error handler is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
ajaxCall() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   jQuery.ajax({
      async: true
      data: { 
         ajaxCallid: "e4f7b812-579b-a347-11f7-ce660ce79b72", 
         javascript: true 
      },
      dataType: "jsonp",
      timeout: 10000,
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://my.site.url.com/my.json"
      xhrFields: { 
         withCredentials: true 
      }
   }).done(function(data) {
      // ...process the data...
      resolve(data);
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     // ... process errors...
     // test the nature of the error, and build an error = {} object
     resolve(error);
   });
 };
}
```

What I am expecting, is that, if I call the following function, and the `https://my.site.url.com/my.json` file does not exist, the `fail` callback of the jquery ajax should be ran, and my Promise should resolve to an `error` object built by the `fail` callback.

Instead of this, the `fail` callback fires, the `error` object is built and returned, but I also get an error in my console, sent by jQuery, that looks something like this:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
>            jQuery 6
>               DOMEval
>               globalEval
>               text script
>               ajaxConvert
>               done
>               callback

It seems to me, that altough an error is fired, jQuery tries to parse the result sent by the server, as a JSON result (which it is not, in the case the file does not exist, apache is throwing a html error message in this case).

If I am correct regarding on the nature of this error, is there any way to tell jQuery, to not try to parse the result as a json, in case any kind of error is being raised, and the `fail` callback is being fired?

I am using `jquery 3.4.1`.

Comment: Most likely the server responds with an error message/page (still coming in as status 200), or sends HTML instead of JSON. Check your server logs for errors, and if no errors, check what exactly the response contains.

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp",` <= of course jQuery is going to try to parse the response as json...

Comment: @Taplar yes, but doesn't jQuery recognize that the server returned an error code, and thus it shouldn't parse the response as `json`?

Comment: Did it return an error code, have you checked the network tab in the DevTools?

Comment: Does it get an error code?  By that, are you seeing a non-2xx or non-3xx response code in the network console?

Comment: Have you tried the `processData` property of the configuration object given to `jQuery.ajax`? See [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Okay, my bad, my apache indeed does not return an error code...